# Call a javascript method from a vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my main.js file I set vue up like so:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('my-component', require('./components/MyComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Also in my main.js file I have a function:

```
function test() {
    //do something
}
```

How can I call the test method from inside a vue component? I know this is not an ideal set up but I'm working with legacy stuff.

Comment: Pass it as a prop. Make it globally accessible. Attache to prototype. Plenty of ways to do it.

Comment: If that function has been declared globally, you can simply call it from inside your Vue component.

Comment: How do I declare it globally?

Comment: I beleive I have declared test() globally, yet the vue component says its still not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its really easy thing :)

inside your main file where you'r having that function

> just declare it globally

```
window.test = function() {
    //do something
}
```

> now you can call this function anywhere from your code / and from any file / from any component :)

```
window.test();
```

if you need anything else please comment.